# Connection timed out using Amazon RDS and EC2

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to connect from an EC2 instance to RDS instance with no success using php.

I tried with these 3 lines to establish a connection (I'm using [MysqliDb](https://github.com/joshcam/PHP-MySQLi-Database-Class) btw):

```
$db = new MysqliDb ('rds_endpoint', 'username', 'password', 'databaseName');
$db = new MysqliDb ('rds_endpoint', 'username', 'password', 'databaseName', 3306);
$db = new MysqliDb ('rds_endpoint:3306', 'username', 'password', 'databaseName',);
```

And when I try to get a table it gives me `2002 Connection timed out`.I checked and the table exists.

Also I checked the Security Groups of both, RDS and EC2 and EC2 inbound rules accepts from all the ips and RDS inbound rules accepts my EC2 instance public IP. I have another Amazon account and tried the above and worked fine, so I don't know where to find errors.

Thanks

Comment: You'll want to whitelist your EC2 instance's **private** IP, not the public one. Better yet, whitelist its security group instead.

Comment: Thanks, now it works!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Turning this into an answer:

You'll want to whitelist your EC2 instance's **private** IP, not the public one. Better yet, whitelist its security group instead.

Instances within AWS will connect to an RDS via the EC2 and RDS instances' internal IP addresses, not their external internet-facing ones.

Whitelisting the *security group* instead of individual IPs means an IP change to the EC2 server will not revoke its RDS access, and means launching new instances into that security group will automatically get the right access.

Comment: Can you explain how to whitelist its security group?  Setting the private IP address worked but I want to figure out how to set the security group.  Thanks

Comment: @tim.paetz You just write the security group's `sg-f0123`-style ID instead of the IP. It'll auto-complete if you start typing the name of one, IIRC.